# How to Verify Check-box is/are checked or Unchecked in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am doing an automation testing of one application and I am facing one scenario to verify Check-box are checked or not using automation code

my web application is developed in angular js and developer used Checked attribute

I tried with .isselected but it was not working for me.

Comment: Can you post your html code for the check box?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a selector that includes the ".ng-not-empty" or "ng-empty" class:

```
List<WebElement> eltsUnchecked = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model='checkboxModel.value1'].ng-empty"));
bool isNotCheched = eltsUnchecked.size() > 0;
if (isNotCheched) {
  // check the checkbox
  eltsUnchecked.get(0).click();
}

List<WebElement> eltsChecked = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model='checkboxModel.value1'].ng-not-empty"));
bool isCheched = eltsChecked.size() > 0;
if (isCheched) {
  // uncheck the checkbox
  eltsChecked.get(0).click();
}
```

Or by checking the presence of ".ng-not-empty" or "ng-empty" in the class attribute :

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model='checkboxModel.value1']"));
bool isCheched = checkbox.getAttribute("class").contains("ng-not-empty");
bool isNotChecked = checkbox.getAttribute("class").contains("ng-empty");
if (isCheched) {
  // uncheck the checkbox
  checkbox.click();
} else if (isNotChecked) {
  // check the checkbox
  checkbox.click();
}
```

But if you are using the "checked" attribute instead then:

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model='checkboxModel.value1']"));
bool isCheched = checkbox.getAttribute("checked").length > 0;
bool isNotChecked = checkbox.getAttribute("checked").length == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi when you want to verify if a Check-box is selected or not then please pay attention that any input tag with type checkbox has a hidden attribute value known as selected if a Check-box is selected then its value is = True and if not then its value is = null,hence on the basis of this you can easily identify which Check-box is selcted or not .below find a working example for the same :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("C:\\Users\\rajnish\\Desktop\\myCheckox.html");

// working with check boxes
// first take all the check boxes inside a list like below
List<WebElement> mycheckBox = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@type='checkbox']"));

// apply the for loop to identify/ verify if a check boxes is selected or not
for(int i=0;i<mycheckBox.size();i++){
    System.out.println("attribut value Selected of Check-box is : " + mycheckBox .get(i).getAttribute("selected"));
    // if Check-box is selected then value of selected attribute is True else null
    if( mycheckBox.get(i).getAttribute("selected").equals("null")){
        // if loop will only run when value of selected attribute is null
        // i.e only when  Check-box is not selected 
        mycheckBox .get(i).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use is selected function

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("element Id"));
el.click()
el.isSelected()
```

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that OP said `isSelected` is NOT working for him.

Comment: Yes, in that case need html source code,might be that is customized dropdown using js

Answer (score 0):

Use isSelected instead of isselected as shown in the following code.

```
Assert.assertEquals(wd.findElement(By.[your element locater])).isSelected(),true);
```

I have successfully used it in my code and its working fine. as below:

```
Assert.assertEquals(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='chkremember']")).isSelected(),true);
```

Comment: `isSelected` didn't work for the OP. I think that it works for me is not a valid answer here.